# convert gridview to excel with original format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have the code below that generates an excel file when clicked. the code runs fine the formatting of colors is fine. The grid view has data with leading zeros that are not showing in excel along with long numbers "106638660952840428" which show up as 1.06639E+17 with a value of 106638660952840000 so it loses its last four digits as well. I have tried several ways to export all with the same results. I am doing it this way to have the chance at formatting the cells individually.So the question is does anyone know how to dynamically change the format so these problems do not occur? Another thing to add is that the grid-view in a web browser does display the data correctly.

```
    protected void LinkButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "blank.aspx");

        if (CheckBox5.Checked || CheckBox6.Checked)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Cache["dtable"];
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=BemisInventory.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                //GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = Color.White;//GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = Color.White;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = Color.White; //GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }            
    }
```

Comment: Fixed by adding: string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"; comes up with warnings but all data is there.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by adding: string style = @" .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } "; comes up with warnings but all data is there.